# How many times can Jane be sued for $10,000 for helping women in Texas get an abortion?

Tags: texas, abortion, texas-sb8

Suppose that Jane lives in Illinois, and she provides help to 30 women in Texas in obtaining abortions. Now suppose that 20 people in various states sue her under Texas law, which says that you can be sued for $10,000 for doing this. Can each person successfully sue Jane 30 times, making her liable for a total of 30x20x$10,000, or six million dollars?

Comment: I don’t think it’s a duplicate: The core of this question essentially is whether groups could conspire to side step the statutory limitations in the cited questions by going to other courts. In essence: The question is whether one could sue under this law outside of Texas, and along those line, could the threshold be side stepped. I’ll vote to reopen if it gets closed.

Comment: I don't see how one can sue outside of Texas under SB8, but suits in multiple Texas counties are clearly allowed, and there is nothing that says such suits can not be filed at essentially the same time.

Comment: This question is a strict subset of the other question, which already has as comprehensive an answer as may be expected, and covers this one as a specific case of the general analysis.

Comment: @kisspuska, I don't understand your comment. Are you suggesting that a person could sue in Virginia courts for a tort specifically created in Texas, one which does not exist under Virginia law?

Comment: @user6726 no, that's what the underlining premise of this question is: "Now suppose that 20 people in various states sue her under Texas law". And if you look at my now-deleted answer, you will see that I was the only person to point out that a court in another state would not allow a cause of action to go forward under this Texas law inexistent anywhere else, but of course, as it has been recently, any answer I give is getting downvoted even the most thoroughly researched ones will prompt never-seen admins to discredit my answers like to a previous question by Greendrake like this one:

Comment: @user6726 https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/75086/expediting-refund-from-a-store-which-takes-time-to-process-it/75234#75234

Comment: @kisspuska **Liquidated** damages must generally be a reasonable attempt to approximate the reasonable value of the damage when it is hard to quantify. That is **not** true of statutory damages, whichg may partake in part o the function of punitive damages, and are often limited only by what a court finds to be "just"; here they are essentially fixed at 10k (+costs) for a given suiy for a single offense (so-called). Nothing in the law imposes  a limit of 10k per offense over all plaintiffs. "*the amount for a single case cannot be more than $10,000*"  (as the law stands) is just what I deny.

Comment: @DavidSiegel yeah, well, +costs, exactly. Over the $10k, there must be prove for them to be awarded. Two filers, even on the same day, if can't prove they had costs in excess of $5k each, will not be awarded a total of more than $10k — likely split between them.

Comment: @kisspuska  There is no provision for split awards, no provision for awards of less than 10k, and no requirement to prove **any** costs to get the 10k. Costs are **in addition** to the 10k.

Answer (score -2):

It’s a Texas state law; none of the 20 persons could sue Jane in any state other than in Texas, and generally only in the state courts of Texas, and not in federal court.

So, for these reasons only, the amount in controversy could not exceed $300,000, as Jane could only be ordered to pay $10,000 for each violation (see, e.g., [Does double jeopardy apply to the Texas abortion bill?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/72629/does-double-jeopardy-apply-to-the-texas-abortion-bill)) and sued only in Texas.

It’s questionable whether a judge would hand down a $300,000 punitive damage order when the interest of the state in deterring recidivism or imitation of outlawed conduct would probably be achieved against an average Jane by a much lower punitive damage amount. Analogously to other types of punitive damages, most likely the maximum multiplier would be less than 10x or less than $100,000 even with 30 violations.

Comment: This conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132643/discussion-on-answer-by-kisspuska-how-many-times-can-jane-be-sued-for-10-000-fo).

Answer (score -4):

No. The law prohibits a court from awarding damages against a person who has already paid the full amount of damages for the conduct at issue in the lawsuit.

Comment: -1 But it does not prohibit awarding damages when a judgement has been given but not yet  paid in full.